# Calling a different function where function name you have is a string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, websocket, aws-lambda

I have been thinking about this for a while now. My environment is NodeJS in AWS running as a lambda function behind a WebSocket API.

I know the name of my messages will be limited, let's say 3-4 and each message will have a different payload.

I can definitely do something like

```
switch(functionName) {
  case "functionA": functionA(jsonBody); break;
  case "functionB": functionB(jsonBody); break;
  case "functionC": functionC(jsonBody); break;
  case "functionD": functionD(jsonBody); break;
}
```

Then in each of my function I can validate my jsonBody to confirm that it confirms to a schema that this function accepts and do processing...

There has to be a better way of not using a switch statement.

I can make use of function.apply but how would I find my "function" from the array.

I think there has to be a cleaner way of calling one of the function if my message name is the same as the function name?

My code looks like

```
module.exports.functionA = async(jsonBody) => {
...
}

module.exports.functionB = async(jsonBody) => {
...
}
```

I have the following JSON when I receive a message my body looks like

```
{
  "action": "sendMessage",
  "payload": {
    "method": "functionA",
    "data": {
      "title": "something"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach you're functions to an object and then call them with property accesors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

```
const myFunctions = {
     functionA:()=> void,
     functionB:()=> void;
}
```

Then access them like so

```
myFunctions[functionName]
```

If you're functions are already part of a class or object, this should  be easy enough

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specifics of your environment But I hope this helps

Comment: I see that, I'm not sure I'm understanding your issue, are you concerned the function won't exist?

Comment: I can do something like this I guess const myFunctions = {
  "addPlayerToGame": addPlayerToGame()
}
but now that I think about it since I am passing a message to web socket I should have n number of function calls for n number of messages thus keeping the code simple